# Prediction GUI not as predict

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tkinter, keras

Can Someone help me fix this. I keep getting error since this is my last one code to running

Code:

```
from tkinter import messagebox 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog 
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename 
import numpy 
import keras 
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import load_model 
from keras import models
from keras import layers 
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers 
main = tkinter.Tk()
main.title("Alzeimers prediction") 
main.geometry("1300x1200")
mapping = numpy.array['MildDemented', 'ModerateDemented', 'NonDemented', 'VeryMildDemented'] 
def load():
    global model
    model = load_model('model_final.h5') 
    model.summary() 
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=1e-4), 
                metrics=['acc'])

def upload():
    text.delete('1.0',END) 
    global filename
    filename = askopenfilename()
    text.insert(END,"File Uploaded: "+str(filename)+"\n") 
    
def imagepreprocess():
    global img4
    img3 = cv2.imread(filename)
    img3 = cv2.cvtColor(img3, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 
    img3 = cv2.resize(img3,(224,224))
    img4 = np.reshape(img3,[1,224,224,3]) 
    
def predict():
    disease = model.predict(img4) 
    prediction = disease[0] 
    prediction_name = mapping[[int(x) for x in prediction]]
    text.insert(END,"Predicted output for uploaded Image: "+str(prediction_name)+"\n") 

font = ('times', 16, 'bold')
title = Label(main, text='Alzeimers Prediction From MRI Images') 
title.config(bg='dark salmon', fg='black')
title.config(font=font) 
title.config(height=3, width=120) 
title.place(x=0,y=5)
font1 = ('times', 14, 'bold')
upload = Button(main, text="Upload Image", command=upload) 
upload.place(x=700,y=100)
upload.config(font=font1)
process = Button(main, text="Image Pre-Processing", command=imagepreprocess) 
process.place(x=700,y=150)
process.config(font=font1)
ld = Button(main, text="Model Load", command=load)
ld.place(x=700,y=200) 
ld.config(font=font1)
pred = Button(main, text="Prediction", command=predict) 
pred.place(x=700,y=250)
pred.config(font=font1) 
font1 = ('times', 12, 'bold')
text=Text(main,height=30,width=80) 
scroll=Scrollbar(text) 
text.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set) 
text.place(x=10,y=100) 
text.config(font=font1) 
main.config(bg='tan1')
main.mainloop()
```

I change

```
prediction_name = mapping[prediction]
```

to this

```
mapping[[int(x) for x  in prediction]]
```

Error:
Then new problem when I upload an image at GUI was non demented but the output at GUI become mild demented 4 times. This is my code i dont know where it's wrong [Predicted output for uploaded Image: ['MildDemented' 'MildDemented' 'MildDemented' 'MildDemented']
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error states that you are trying to use a non-integer array as a way to index your `mapping` array.
It is only possible to use interger arrays to do indexing, for example [1,0,1,2,4]. Here I think you have something like  [1.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,4.0].
Try the following to convert your elements to integers instead of floats:

```
mapping[[int(x) for x  in prediction]]
```

in your predict function.

EDIT: Your `mapping` list cannot be indexed by a list of indices since the list object does not allow this kind of indexing. To solve the new error, you can convert it to a numpy array when you define it:

```
mapping = numpy.array(['MildDemented', 'ModerateDemented', 'NonDemented', 'VeryMildDemented'])
```

Numpy arrays allow the indexing by a list of indices.

Also, please do not forget to keep the prediction_name definition in the code you changed:

```
prediction_name = mapping[[int(x) for x  in prediction]]
```

Comment: I edited my answer for your second error

Comment: okay i have done that then my gui prediction become like i posted above